# Which is the smallest available widebody on the market?

Tags: aircraft-design, airline-operations

I'm interested to find out which is the smallest (capacity wise) modern widebody aircraft in production/ operation.

Comment: Smallest in which measure(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the number of rows of seats can vary within a type, I propose the 767.  Narrowest inside width (4.72 m), [fewest seats per row](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-body_aircraft#Comparison) in economy (2-3-2).
For instance, [United's 767-300 "Version 3 (46/121)"](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/inflight/aircraft/767-300er.html#v3) with a small economy class section has 46+22+43+56 = only 167 seats.

Answer (score 11):

This question is broad enough to try out the new table feature:

| Smallest by | All time | In production |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MTOW | Airbus A310-200 (144t) | Boeing 767-300F (186.9t) |
| Length | Airbus A310-200 (46.66m) | Boeing 767-300F (54.94m) |
| Outside Width | Boeing 767 (5.03m) | Boeing 767 (5.03m) |
| max. Payload | Airbus A310-200 (32.8t) | Boeing 787-8 (43.3t) |
| Exit Limit | Airbus A310-200 (275) | Boeing 787-8 (381) |
| Passengers* | Boeing 767-200 (214) | Boeing 787-8 (242) |
| Seats Across* | Boeing 767 (7) | Airbus A330neo (8) |

<sup>* number of seats for typical 2-class layout, seats across for typical economy</sup>
(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-body_aircraft#Comparison))

In summary, the Airbus A310 was the smallest wide-body ever produced by most measures. The smallest wide-body still in production today is the Boeing 767, but only the freighter variant is still produced. The smallest passenger wide-body in production is the Boeing 787 Dreamliner.

Comment: I upvoted the 'by which measure comment', you just answered for all measures. Nice! +1. And good use of the new table feature!

Comment: For number of passengers, Wikipedia's table is incomplete.  Seating varies within each type, and therein even within each airline.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune I know, that's why I listed exit limit first. It is a clearly defined number. For passengers I listed what Wikipedia listed as typical in a 2-class layout. Actual numbers can vary a lot of course.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  +1.